# Python Flask Restful and Sqlalchemy with postgres: Tables not created

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I want to connect to a postgres database running in my dev docker container.
I can establish a connection by the connection String:

```
def create_api():
    from .models import db
    from .models.userModels import User
    # Initialize and Configure the Flask App
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(AppConfig)
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I have a separate module for my routes and the related classes as well as a separate module for my models I will use for postgres model based communication.

In the init file I execute the create_api() method. Here I create the routes and connect them to a Resource class ( userResource.py).
In userReource.py I use the userModels.User for my db stuff.

Structure:

```
- api
 __init__.py
 - models
   - userModels.py
 - resources
   - userResource.py
```

Model:

```
 class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(100))
   
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
```

The docs[enter link description here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) say that I should use the

db.create_all() method to create the table user id if not exists.
I've also read other answsers of that topic which mention to import the model class if it is placed in a separate module before executing this command. As you can see, I've imported the model before, but nothing happens in my database.

Is there something else I have to take care of?

Comment: Where is `db.create_all()` getting called?

Comment: I think in `create_api` function, you need to return app